# Polymorphism: How to make the compiler aware of the returned implementation of method which return type is an interface?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Say I have a class `PhoneShop` that has a `getPhone` method that needs to be backwards compatible (we have to keep the arguments that we pass the same - this is a simplified version of a code test I've been given although I've changed the names of everything and I've been told that the API of the PhoneShop class should stay the same)

So far we only have one phone type, `Nokia`, and we can get it like this:

```
PhoneShop shop = new PhoneShop();
Phone nokia = shop.getPhone("Nokia");
nokia.call();
```

I want to change the `Phone` class to be an interface to allow multiple classes to implement it

```
public interface Phone {
    String getName();
    void call();
}
```

PhoneShop getPhone

```
public class PhoneShop {
    public Phone getPhone(String name) {
        return new Nokia();
    }
}
```

Nokia

```
public class Nokia implements Phone {

    public String getName() {
        return "Nokia";
    }
    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Calling from my " + getName());
    }
}
```

So far the string argument is being passed but it isn't used by the business logic but now we have a new Phone type, Samsung:

```
public class Samsung implements Phone {
    public String getName() {
        return "Samsung";
    }
    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Calling from my " + getName());
    }

    public void browseInternet() {
        System.out.println("Browsing internet with my " + getName());
    }
}
```

and now I want to also be able to call getPhone like this

```
  Phone samsung = shop.getPhone("Samsung");
  samsung.call();
  samsung.browseInternet();
```

```
public Phone getPhone(String name) {
   return switch (name) {
       case "Samsung" -> new Samsung();
       default -> new Nokia();
    };
}
```

This code won't compile because `browseInternet` is not defined on the `Phone` interface.

How can I let the compiler know that when I call `getPhone` with the string "Samsung" I actually have an instance of Samsung?

With only two phone types I could overload the method, so that eg. when it's called with no arguments, it returns an instance of `Samsung` but as I add more phone types  I won't have that option. Also that's not a great API - it's not obvious to the caller.

The only way I can get it to compile so far is to cast the return type like this

```
Samsung samsung = (Samsung) shop.getPhone("Samsung");
```

I don't really like that because it's open to developer error (I could mistakenly cast it to Nokia for example, and then I'd get a runtime error.

I'd like to be able to tell the compiler, "if I call this method with this particular string then it has this return type", but I don't think you can do that(?). In which case is there a pattern (factory pattern, generics ?) that I can use? (I am a newbie to Java and OOP in general - much more familiar with JavaScript and TypeScript).

Comment: Add `void browseInternet();` to `Phone`. Because you **can** *browse internet* on both types of phone. If you're concerned about non-Internet phones then add another intermediate interface called `SmartPhone` that has `void browseInternet()`.

Comment: Side note while I'm reading: get rid of the `String name` in the `interface`, use something like `String getName();` instead (which can then be overridden by subclasses appropriately).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ElliotFrisch. I should have made it clearer that I want to model that difference. An instance of Nokia should not have 'browseInternet" but Samsung should. So the requirement is that getPhone should be able to return objects of different types, all of which extend Phone, but I want some of them to have their own specific properties/methods

Comment: As far as a suggestion for making this compiler-aware, you could have a `<T extends Phone> T getPhone(Class<T> clazz) {...}`, allowing you to use it as `Samsung phone = shop.getPhone(Samsung.class);` (and perhaps `#getNewPhone` is a better name). From there you can use any number of construction rules/patterns to determine the internal logic

Comment: Why use a `String` at all? What *type* should the method return if it was called with a string not known at compile time? How would `getPhone(new Random().nextBoolean() ? "Nokia" : "Samsung")` work? That cannot be assigned to either `Nokia` or `Samsung`. How about taking a `Class` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined Phone as something that cannot browse the internet, hence, when you manipulate your objects as Phones, you cannot browse the internet.

Polymorphism will allow you to manipulate Samsung and Nokia objects as Phones for the sake of abstraction, if you want to use their behaviors as concrete implementation, you have to explicitly do so (Java is a strongly typed language).

Now if you want to avoid casts because of reliability (rightfully), another way is to test that a Phone is in fact a Samsung phone before calling a Samsung behavior :

```
if (samsung instanceof Samsung concreteSamsungPhone) {
        concreteSamsungPhone.browseInternet();
    }
```

this test will automatically use pattern matching to map your Phone to the concrete implementation of a Samsung if it is actually a Samsung (this feature is only available in recent versions of java though).

btw you are intuitively using a Factory Pattern :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single abstract type, create an interface with `browseInternet` that extends `Phone`:

```
interface InternetPhone extends Phone {
    void browseInternet();
}
```

That the Samsung would implement and check the type at the usage point:

```
if (phone instanceof InternetPhone browser) {
    browser.browseInternet();
}
```

---

If you can separate the abstractions, which is cleaner, don't extend `Phone`:

```
interface Browser {
    void browseInternet();
}
```

And have Samsung extend both:

```
class Samsung implements Phone, Browser {
```

The usage code would be the same.

---

An aside: If you want `getName()` to return the name of the class (like all of your examples do), you can implement that in the interface definition using the `default` keyword:

```
public interface Phone {
    default String getName() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
    void call();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

P.S.: Before continue reading this answer, consider reading [this comment from Rogue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76087013/how-to-call-a-function-that-has-an-interface-as-its-return-type-so-that-the-com/76087604#comment134186723_76087013) to see if his approach doesn't meet your needs.

---

If I was able to understand your situation, you want to leverage Java’s polymorphism. However, I don’t understand why you have created classes for each phone manufacturer, since your hole point is that you have two different types of phone, and what differentiates them is the name of each model/manufacturer.

Of course, your real situation may be different, and you may have missed something when building your example. Because of this, I’ll propose you two different approaches, among several you can take advantage of, both leveraging inheritance and polymorphism.

#### Approach 1:

Instead of create a different class for each different manufacturer, since all that matters is the phone type, why doesn’t you create two classes: `Phone` and `Smartphone`, where phones can only make calls and smartphones can either make calls and browse internet? In this design, `Smartphone` inherit from `Phone`, since a `Smartphone` **IS A** `Phone`:

```java
public class Phone {
    private String name;

    protected Phone(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Calling from my " + getName());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Smartphone extends Phone {

    public Smartphone(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void browsingInternet() {
        System.out.println("Browsing internet with my " + getName());
    }
}
```

```java
public class PhoneShop {

    public PhoneShop() {
    }

    public Phone getPhone(String phoneName) {
        return new Phone(phoneName);
    }

    public Smartphone getSmartphone(String smartphoneName) {
        return new Smartphone(smartphoneName);
    }
}
```

#### Approach 2:

If the phone manufacturers or models matter, then the phone types, i.e., whether they’re simple phones or smartphones, can be abstract classes that will be inherited by the phone models. To simplify, I’ll assume that “Nokia” and “Samsung”, although manufacturers, are like phone models.

```java
public abstract class Phone {
    private String name;

    protected Phone(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Calling from my " + getName());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
public abstract class Smartphone extends Phone {

    protected SmartPhone(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void browsingInternet() {
        System.out.println("Browsing internet with my " + super.getName());
    }
}
```

Note that `Smartphone` inherits the functionalities of `Phone`, which is the one and only `call()` method in this situation. This way, your phones model or manufacturer classes will be very simple and your code easy to maintain:

```java
public class Samsung extends Smartphone {

    public Samsung(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Nokia extends Phone {

    public Nokia(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

In this situation, you may want to reduce the possibility of mistakes by wrongly typing the manufacturer’s name. You can do it by creating a very simple `Enum` class, that would be used as argument for your factory methods.

```java
public enum PhoneManufacturer {
    SAMSUNG,
    NOKIA
}
```

```java
public class PhoneShop {

    public PhoneShop() {
    }

    // Factory method
    public Phone getDevice(PhoneManufacturer manufacturer) {
        switch (manufacturer) {
            case NOKIA -> {
                return new Nokia(manufacturer.name().charAt(0) + manufacturer.name().substring(1).toLowerCase());
            }
            case SAMSUNG -> {
                return new Samsung(manufacturer.name().charAt(0) + manufacturer.name().substring(1).toLowerCase());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you want a `Phone` or `Smartphone`, you can simply do the following:

```java
PhoneShop phoneShop = new PhoneShop();

Phone nokia = phoneShop.getDevice(PhoneManufacturer.NOKIA);
Smartphone samsung = (Smartphone) phoneShop.getDevice(PhoneManufacturer.SAMSUNG);
```

Note that if you want to call `Smartphone` specific methods, such as `browsingInternet()`, you'll need to cast the object returned from the `PhoneShop#getDevice`, otherwise, it'll be just an ordinary `Phone`.

Comment: That `PhoneShop#getDevice` is pretty evil, since it allows you to do this: `Nokia phone = shop.getDevice(PhoneManufacturer.SAMSUNG);` with no compile error. I think your advice on design is meritable, just take that all the way and remove the need for generics.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, Rogue. I missed that. The answer was edited following your advice.